# during magento installation i got Database server does not support InnoDB

Tags: magento, innodb

I am trying to install latest magento version on jaquarpc. When i entered the database name,username and password it throws an error saying

> ```
>        Database server does not support InnoDB storage engine
>        Database connection error
> ```

I also referred to magento forums..http://www.magentocommerce.com/boards/viewthread/33904/P0/
But did not get any solution.Can anyone help me with this pls?

Answer (score 1):

It means what it says: your installation of MySQL is compiled or configured not to provide any support for the ‘InnoDB’ database backend. The alternative and default database backend, ‘MyISAM’, is largely undesirable as it does not offer the data-integrity features that robust applications require.

If you have access to the `my.cnf` on your server, edit it to see if you can re-enable InnoDB support (by eg. removing any `skip-innodb` statement). If not, you'll need to install or compile your own copy of MySQL that hasn't been neutered in this way.

If you are on some sort of shared hosting where you don't have access to any of this stuff, you'll have to move to a different host or plan that doesn't lump you with a pathetically broken MySQL install.

It may be possible to make Magento run on MyISAM by hacking its code to remove `ENGINE=InnoDB` from its schema-creation code, but you don't really want to run anything critical on MyISAM.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the MySQL version 5.6 you may get this error, so try using a MySQL Version earlier than 5.6 since I tried myself and I got this error on Mysql version 5.6, but when I tried it in the earlier version of Mysql there was no such issue like Database server does not support the InnoDB storage engine.